# iOS - UIWebView - weird concatenation to url

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, nsurl

I have a `UIWbView` and I load it with an encoded url: `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%0A`

When i debug, and stop at:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

the `[[request URL] absoluteString]` returns

```
{ URL: file://http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%0A }
```

The framework added `file://` prefix, WHY??? I didn't ask for that... :/

Comment: could you show some of that code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It assumed it was a `file://` URL as it didn't find a [URL scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) in `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%0A`.

Change the URL to `http://www.google.com` and it will be fine (that trailing `%0A` is also suspicious).

Comment: I m checking, but can u explain why?